# IOC life cycle and static class

Tags: dependency-injection, static

Does discussing the behavior of static classes make sense for IOC?

It seems that in the case of a life cycle transient such a description is misleading and untrue:

> However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program. A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

Static class can be used by IOC. I can configure it as Transient. In such a case, the constructor will be called many times in the program.

Sorry for My English.

Comment: Asking if something "makes sense" leads to opinionated answers, which makes this question a poor fit for this community. I'm also unfamiliar with the term "lifestyle transient". Can you define that better? And how is the quoted text misleading?

Comment: I read that as meaning the class will be constructed and still exist when you go to use it. How is that “misleading “ or “untrue”?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I suspect "lifestyle" should be "lifecycle".

Comment: And by "DI engines" do you mean "DI frameworks" or "IOC containers" (IOC = Inversion of Control)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt DI is part of IOC. I mean the element that calls the constructors. So it be IOC.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to use a static class with IOC/DI in .net. Are you sure you made your class static, and not just added a static constructor? Or made a static instance of your class? You might want to post an example of what you have actually done.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "life cycle" and DI "frameworks"?

I think here you are confusing static classes and singletons. You can use static classes and constructors to make singletons, but in the context of DI frameworks "singleton" is more likely to mean an instance that is shared rather than having a scoped lifecycle.

As opposed to a "true" singleton, where the language itself prevents more than one instance existing at a time by using things like static, a DI singleton lifecycle can be used with any class. The DI framework makes sure the same instance is always used for everything that needs it.